# How does Superman control his enhanced hearing?

Tags: dc, superman

How does Superman control his super-hearing? How does he manage to live in a large city without it being a hindrance?

Comment: How does Superman enhance his hearing?

Comment: The same way he avoids killing the whole world every time he sneezes. It's called "self-control" :-)

Answer (score 5):

The DC Wiki states that "[He has shown enough control to block out ambient sounds to focus on a specific source/frequency](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_(Clark_Kent))." Since he is able to focus on particular sounds, Superman can just focus on the sounds in his immediate area, and therefore only have to process nearby goings-on. Superman also has a very strong will and large intellect, and so would be much less overwhelmed by a large intake of information than normal humans.